# Vertical bundle of a principal bundle. Isn't it always trivial?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

I may be totally wrong here, but after a bit of studying I've reach the conclusion of the title. My reasoning is as follows:

For a principal bundle $P(M,G),$ and $VP$ is vertical bundle, let $\sigma : \mathfrak g \to \mathfrak X(P)$  be the fundamental vector field Lie algebra morphism. Since the bundle is principal, fundamental vector fields are all vertical vector fields. Now, fix a basis $\{e_1,\dotsc. e_k\}$ of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g, $ where $k$ is its dimension.  The vector fields $E_i = \sigma(e_i), \ i = 1\dotsc, k$ are smooth vector fields which form a basis of $V_p$ at each point $p \in P,$ since at each point $p,$ the mapping  $\sigma_p : X \in \mathfrak g \mapsto (\sigma(X))_p\in V_p $ is an isomorphism. So we have a global smooth frame for $VP,$ which means $VP$ is a trivial vector bundle.

I'm a bit cautious about this affirmation since I haven't seen any comments about it on lectures notes nor books I've looked so far, but I can't see any issues in my argument.

Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.  You can think of this as a generalization of the fact that the tangent bundle of $G$ is trivial.  Indeed, when the bundle $P\cong M\times G$ is trivial, $VP$ can be identified with the pullback of the tangent bundle of $G$.  The trivialization of $VP$ thus obtained will actually be preserved by the transitions between different local trivializations of $P$, since those transitions correspond to multiplying by elements of $G$ on each fiber, and our trivialization of $TG$ is translation-invariant.  So, the local trivializations of $VP$ combine to give a global trivialization, even if $P$ is not trivial.

Comment: May I ask a question in this regard : So for the trivial bundle $M \times G \to M$ the vertical bundle is $ P = M \times G \times g$ while the tangent bundle as a whole is $TM \times G \times g$. Then is a connection on $P$ a complement of $M$ inside $TM$? (seen as zero section). How does one produce a "trivial" connection then?

Comment: Of course $g$ = Lie($G$)